# Progress 8, CURRENT_DATE select

Tags: date, progress-db

I´d like to execute a statement on my Progress DB (Major Version 8) which would look like this in SQL Server:

Select GETDATE()

or

Select Current_Date from DUAL

with Oralce

With Progress8, the date regisiter is, CURRENT_DATE.
My question is now: does a table like dual exist for Progress8 ? Or is this statement, that returns just a Date not possible ?
(I could create a Table like the DUAL Table, but i don´t have permission to it)

Answer (score 0):

Progress is not SQL.  Progress version 8 is also ancient, obsolete and unsupported.  It was released in the 90s.    The current version of Progress is OpenEdge 11 (the "OpenEdge" branding was introduced with version 9).

FWIW Progress 8 does have some very limited SQL-89 features but using them is generally considered crazy.  They were added to the language in the dark ages for marketing purposes.  You will be much more successful writing your query using the 4GL.

If you are actually trying to do this from within the 4GL then you are looking for the TODAY keyword.

Modern versions of Progress do support SQL-92 access via ODBC or JDBC.  But you need to upgrade to get that.

Comment: Thank you for the information with the 4GL, i and my coworkers didn´t know this. It´s good to know to have this option if we get stuck.

Upgrading would be helpfull, but it´s a customers database, so no chance for us. Thank you!